# Making A Cool Down Timer For Multiple Users

Tags: c#, timer, discord.net

So I'm currently developing a Discord Bot, and I have a problem on how I could make a cool down timer for a command. So I want it so if they use a command, then they get added to a list, and have to wait amount of seconds until they can use the command. I have a somewhat idea on how to do this, but I'm mainly stuck at the part of having multiple cool down timers for different people. So lets say as a reference. User1 uses the command, now he has to wait 5 seconds until he uses it again. Then User2 uses the command, and he also has to wait 5 seconds. Well User2 used the command 3 seconds in of the cool down for User1. So basically I'm asking how could I make a timer that kept track of each users time. Then once that specific users cool down is done, he gets removed from a list. I planned to store the users that are on cool down into a list.

I might be overthinking this, so sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The way that I did it was by making it so the program declares 2 empty lists near the start, one containing DateTimeOffset and the other SocketGuildUser. You could tie the two into a list of object instances, if you want your code to be a little more efficient and bug-resistant. For the sake of the example however:

Declare your lists at the start of your program.

```
public static List<DateTimeOffset> stackCooldownTimer = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
public static List<SocketGuildUser> stackCooldownTarget = new List<SocketGuildUser>();
```

Here's the rate limit code:

```
//Check if your user list contains who just used that command.
if (Program.stackCooldownTarget.Contains(Context.User as SocketGuildUser))
{
    //If they have used this command before, take the time the user last did something, add 5 seconds, and see if it's greater than this very moment.
    if (Program.stackCooldownTimer[Program.stackCooldownTarget.IndexOf(Context.Message.Author as SocketGuildUser)].AddSeconds(5) >= DateTimeOffset.Now)
    {
            //If enough time hasn't passed, reply letting them know how much longer they need to wait, and end the code.
            int secondsLeft = (int) (Program.stackCooldownTimer[Program.stackCooldownTarget.IndexOf(Context.Message.Author as SocketGuildUser)].AddSeconds(5) - DateTimeOffset.Now).TotalSeconds;
            await ReplyAsync($"Hey! You have to wait at least {secondsLeft} seconds before you can use that command again!");
            return;
    }
    else
    {
        //If enough time has passed, set the time for the user to right now.
        Program.stackCooldownTimer[Program.stackCooldownTarget.IndexOf(Context.Message.Author as SocketGuildUser)] = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }
}
else
{
    //If they've never used this command before, add their username and when they just used this command.
    Program.stackCooldownTarget.Add(Context.User as SocketGuildUser);
    Program.stackCooldownTimer.Add(DateTimeOffset.Now);
}
```

From here, type whatever you want your code to do if they pass.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is to use an `IMemoryCache` instance which can be propagated throughout your application using the DI container.

Basically, you want to attach an event to `_client.MessageRecieved` and handle it - something like this can suffice:

```c#
private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

public async Task HandleMessage(SocketMessage message)
{
    // Get the key we will use to search
    string key = GetUserCooldownCacheKey(message.Author.Id);

    // Check if the item we are using for the cooldown is still in memory
    // (it can be discarded)
    bool cacheValue = _cache.TryGetValue(key, out _);

    if (cacheValue)
    {
        // Logic if cooldown is not over here
        return;
    }

    // What you want to do when the cooldown is over
    TimeSpan cooldown = // set your cooldown here;

    // add an object to the cache that will be deleted after the cooldown
    _cache.Set(key, new object(), cooldown);
}

public static string GetUserCooldownCacheKey(ulong userId)
{
    // The key we will use for locating if the cooldown for the
    // user is still active
    return $"message-{userId}";
}
```